# Rails Cancan load_resource with nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am having a problem that I thought would have been answered somewhere but I cannot find it So I have my route like this

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update] do                                                                                                                                            
  get :resend_invitation                                                                                                                       
end
```

So of course the `:resend_invitation` route looks like this `/users/:user_id/resend_invitation`

It seems like Cancan only loads resources with the `:id` parameter. I cannot find in the docs how to specify to include the `:user_id` parameter as well. I just want to automatically load my resources for my nested routes as well.

If anyone has any insight I would be very grateful.

Thanks

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

My end goal is that I want @user to be populated in my nested routes

```
def resend_invitation
    # @user = User.find(params[:user_id] done by cancan
    @user.something
end
```

Comment: i dont understand what you want, u want a @user object to be available for you?

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hav tim, check this in cancan's github:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/178#issuecomment-486203

also this:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-Controller-Actions

there is your answer

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I am not sure that awnsers what I am getting at. I am not worried about authorizing the action I was hoping that it would load the resource for me with the :user_id param as well.

Comment: as soon as you authroize it and load it you will have the @user variable available